# TouchesEnded event

Tags: objective-c, touch

I have created a view which has an object `img` which is a subclass of `UIImageView` and I have added the `touchesEnded` method to the `img` class. But when I click on the `img` class object, the `touchesEnded event` is not triggered.

Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong, please?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll have to implement all four event handling methods: `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`. If that doesn't help, please be more precise about your question. "has an object" is very ambiguous. what is "img class"

Comment: Also, look at using gesture recognizers if your deployment target is 3.2 or higher, they save a lot of time and headaches of handling these types of things yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` by default has `userInteractionEnabled` property set to NO so it does not track any touch events. Try to set userInteractionEnabled to YES